# How do I delete users (for custom user model)?

Tags: python, django

I want to delete all users, including superusers from my custom user model. On Django's default model, I know you can call Users.objects.all().delete() but when I try to call something similar on my own model, it says there is no delete() function. Is there something I can follow to write this function or is there an easier way to delete all users from my custom model?

Comment: Please publish your code - your custom **model** and other code, so others will be able to see what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: And show your traceback.